# Лямбда выражения: захват переменной по ссылке или передача параметра по ссылке

Tags: c++, lambda, замыкания, передача-параметров

В C++ в лямбда выражениях есть  два способа обратиться к значению переменной:

1) Передать переменную в качестве параметра по ссылке:

```
int main() {
  int a = 5;
  auto f = [](int &a) {
    cout << "lambda var = " << a << endl;
    a = 7;
  };
  f(a);
  cout << "main var = " << a << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

2) Захватить переменную по ссылке

```
int main() {
  int a = 5;
  auto f = [&a]() {
    cout << "lambda var = " << a << endl;
    a = 7;
  };
  f();
  cout << "main var = " << a << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

И первый и второй случай компилируются и выдают одинаковый результат. И в первом и во втором случае можно менять значение переменной.

В большинстве примеров и обзоров лямбд пишут, что если вам надо менять значение переменных, то используйте захват по ссылке. Про передачу параметра по ссылке обычно даже не упомянают, но оба способа рабочие.

В чем разница? Зачем существует захват/замыкание, когда переменную можно просто передать в качестве параметра?

P.S. Понимаю, что приведенные примеры кода просты до безобразия, но, мне кажется, на простом примере проще разобраться.

Comment: Ну, например, в некотором алгоритме вам нужен функтор от одной переменной. И переменную эту передает алгоритм. А вычисления функтора требуют еще одного параметра - и куда вы будете его засовывать? Ну, простоты для - через `for_each` увеличить все значения элементов вектора на *некоторое число*. И куда это число передать?...

Comment: Harry,  спасибо за самый понятный и нужный ответ. С удовольствием бы отметил именно ваш комментарий как верный ответ.

Comment: Нет вопросов - оформил как ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представим, например, некоторый алгоритм, которому нужно передавать функтор от одной переменной. И эту переменную в качестве аргумента передает сам алгоритм.

Но вычисление функтора в вашей конкретной задаче требует наличия еще одного параметра - и куда его можно передать?

Простейший пример - через `for_each` увеличить все значения элементов вектора на **некоторое число**. И как это число передать, кроме как путем захвата?..

Answer (score 4):

Вы сравниваете несравнимое.
Замыкание позволяет передать в лямбда-функцию контекст, в котором она была создана. 
При этом в месте, где эта лямбда функция будет реально вызываться (а это может быть где-то совсем в другом месте, в чужом коде), этот контекст чаще всего будет недоступен. Т.е. не получится сделать так, как в вашем примере - передать ссылку на переменную в качестве параметра. У вас же пример утрированный - вы создаете лямбда-функцию и тут же ее вызываете.

Answer (score 2):

Первый пример (по ссылке):

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;
  auto f = [](int &l) {
    cout << "lambda var = " << l << endl;
    l = 7;
  };
  f(a);
  f(b);
```

В этом случае аргументом в лямбду передаётся адрес переменной. В каждом вызове может присутствовать разные адреса. А переменная a в лямбде это всего-лишь локальная. И может иметь имя какое угодно.

Во втором  примере будет автоматически компилятором генерироваться такой вариант:

```
int a = 5;
  auto f = [](int * __pointer_to_local_var__) {
    cout << "lambda var = " << (* __pointer_to_local_var__) << endl;
    (* __pointer_to_local_var__) = 7;
  };
  f(&a);
```

И аргументом автоматически будет запихиваться именно переменная a.